# How To Get Difference Between Two Template Literal Types In Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, template-literals

Given the following example snippet:

```
const firstName = `Abraham` as const;
const fullName = `${firstName}Lincoln` as const;

type FullName = typeof fullName;
type FirstName = typeof firstName;

// type LastName = "Lincoln"
```

The goal is to get access to the `LastName` type without writing it out, considering that the `firstName` is known and that the `lastName` is already contained inside the `fullName`.

I've tried [two similar approaches](http://const%20firstName%20=%20%60Abraham%60%20as%20const;%20const%20fullName%20=%20%60$%7BfirstName%7DLincoln%60%20as%20const;%20%20type%20FullName%20=%20typeof%20fullName;%20type%20FirstName%20=%20typeof%20firstName;%20%20type%20GetLastName%3CFirstName%20extends%20string,%20Name%20extends%20%60$%7BFirstName%7D$%7BLastName%7D%60,%20LastName%20extends%20string%20=%20string%3E%20=%20LastName;%20type%20LastName%20=%20GetLastName%3CFirstName,%20FullName%3E;%20%20const%20getLastName%20=%20%3CFirstName%20extends%20string,%20LastName%20extends%20string,%20Name%20extends%20%60$%7BFirstName%7D$%7BLastName%7D%60%3E(firstName:%20FirstName,%20fullName:%20Name):%20LastName%20=%3E%20fullName.split(firstName).join(%27%27)%20as%20LastName;%20const%20lastName%20=%20getLastName(firstName,%20fullName);%20console.log(lastName);%20//%20%27Lincoln%27), none of which was fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const firstName = `Abraham` as const;
const fullName = `${firstName}Lincoln` as const;

type FullName = typeof fullName;
type FirstName = typeof firstName;


type Difference<T extends string, U extends string> = 
  // T is the common part
  // Scd is the difference we want to retrieve
  U extends `${T}${infer Scd}` ? Scd : never

type Result = Difference<FirstName, FullName> // Lincoln
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7QHIEMC2BTGBeGAAwEEAjJdACy0JnQhlEigG4BYAKCengFcAbfhhz4iAEgDeiFFGHYAvgBkEYUPzC16jcNHYdOUAJ4AHXADEBQrLgJHTIOH0Fy9d88jTXRbh-A%20zrPU4DE1wAUQAPKApgKAARBDg4bCRsVWwAHgAVGGwotIATBmgkFQBzABoYAFVc-LAimBLygD5RWryoQoZCSSz5SRVkpBgAZWAC%20VoAfjGJmAAuGDBsADcU4I43GAAlbAgBWAJI6PRYhKSUtOBMs385KotnazaAeleYZVUQdSA)